# how to automatically scroll horizontal listview to a selected item in android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

In my application i am using a HorizontalScroll Listview to create a calendar like below : 
[image: Calendar]

The current is getting selected on load of this fragment. The only issue is that when the current date is a date which is going beyond the screen size, the selected date is not visible . the user has to manually scroll the listview to get to the selected date.

I want the list to scroll automatically to the selected date. 
I did a lot of answers but were only applicable in a vertical scroll listview not a horizontallistview.

The library that i am using for horizontal listview is [here.](http://pastie.org/10467723)

Please help ! Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Did you try with `HorizontalScrollListview.setSelection(position);` ?

Comment: @Rami yes i did..The list item appears to be selected, but it does not bring the item to the top of the list view

Comment: You want to move the selected item to the extreme left? just after "Oct 15"?

Comment: **horizontalScrollView.scrollBy(yourposition, 0);**
(or)
**horizontalScrollView.scrollTo(160, 0);**

Comment: @shivani Yes, I have the same task but still not completed, Please share with me once if you are done that one.

Comment: @TrickySolutions no sorry! Its not working! any othe solutions?

Comment: @sakthi i too could find a solution for this yet1 If you did find one, please help me out.

Comment: @shivani I tried this one, but not working as a center                                           int scrollX = (v.getLeft() - (ConstantKey.mDeviceDimen.x / 2)) + (v.getWidth() / 2);  HScrollView.smoothScrollTo(scrollX, 0);